# KOMA script : appendix TOC with etoc package wrong label names

Tags: hyperref, labels, etoc

I use the etoc-package together with KOMA-script class scrreprt to create a appendix sub TOC. This sub TOC lists all appendices on section level down to subsubsections. The appendix titles are not added to the main TOC (but to bookmarks) and the titles are not printed but added to the header. For this purpose I created `\appendixsection`, ... commands. Hyperref also creates links to the location of my appendices but somehow `\def\@currentlabelname{#1}` does not generate the correct label names.

[image]

The correct label names would be: A.1 Appendix , A.1.1 Sub-Appendix , A.1.1.1 Subsub-Appendix.
Hase anyone an idea how to fix this issue.

Here's my MWE.

```
\documentclass[
a4paper,
11pt,
parskip=half,
numbers=noenddot,
openright,
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{footnotebackref} % Loads hyperref
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\setkomafont{chapterentry}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\spacing{1.3}

\hypersetup{
    hypertexnames=false,
    colorlinks=true,
    citecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black,
    bookmarksnumbered,
    bookmarksdepth=2,
    bookmarksopenlevel=1,
    bookmarksopen=true,
}

% Header
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\KOMAoption{headsepline}{true}
\ohead{\pagemark}
\renewcommand{\headfont}{\normalfont}
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\ihead{\headmark}

% Typearea
\newlength{\pageleftmargin}
\newlength{\pagerightmargin}
\newlength{\pagetopmargin}
\newlength{\pagebottommargin}
\setlength{\pageleftmargin}{35mm}
\setlength{\pagerightmargin}{15mm}
\setlength{\pagetopmargin}{30mm}
\setlength{\pagebottommargin}{25mm}

\geometry{
    landscape=false,
    twoside=true,
    showframe=true,
    left=\pageleftmargin,
    right=\pagerightmargin,
    top=\pagetopmargin,
    bottom=\pagebottommargin,   
}

% PDF inclue settings
\newlength{\pdfoffsetX}
\setlength{\pdfoffsetX}{(\pageleftmargin-\pagerightmargin)/2}
\newlength{\pdfoffsetY}
\setlength{\pdfoffsetY}{(\pagetopmargin-\pagebottommargin)/2}
\includepdfset{pagecommand={},width=\textwidth,offset=\pdfoffsetX mm -\pdfoffsetY mm}

% Appendix
\appto\appendix{\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}}
\appto\appendix{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}}}
\appto\appendix{\hypersetup{bookmarksdepth=3}}
\appto\appendix{\automark[section]{section}
                \automark*[subsection]{subsection}
                \automark*[subsubsection]{subsubsection}}

% Appendix TOC
\newcommand{\appendixtoc}{
    \etocsettocdepth.toc{chapter}\etocignoretoctocdepth
    \etocsetnexttocdepth{subsubsubsection}
    \etocsettocstyle{}{}
    \KOMAoptions{parskip=never}
    \localtableofcontents
    \KOMAoptions{parskip=half}
    \clearpage
}

% Phantom titles for appendices
\newcommand{\appendixsection}[1]{
    \stepcounter{section}%
    \makeatletter\def\@currentlabelname{#1}\makeatother%
    \phantomsection%
    \addxcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}#1}%
    \sectionmark{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\appendixsubsection}[1]{
    \stepcounter{subsection}%
    \makeatletter\def\@currentlabelname{#1}\makeatother%
    \phantomsection%
    \addxcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\protect\numberline{\thesubsection}#1}%
    \subsectionmark{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\appendixsubsubsection}[1]{
    \stepcounter{subsubsection}%
    \makeatletter\def\@currentlabelname{#1}\makeatother%
    \phantomsection%
    \addxcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{\protect\numberline{\thesubsubsection}#1}%
    \subsubsectionmark{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter 1}

Reference to appendix \ref{app: Appendix Section} \nameref{app: Appendix Section}.\\
Reference to sub-appendix \ref{app: Appendix Subsection} \nameref{app: Appendix Subsection}.\\
Reference to subsub-appendix \ref{app: Appendix Subsubsection} \nameref{app: Appendix Subsubsection}.

\section{Section 1}
\section{Section 2}

\appendix
\chapter{Appendices}

\appendixtoc

%\includepdf[pages=1,pagecommand={\appendixsection{First Appendix} \label{app: Appendix Section}}]{TestA4.pdf}
\appendixsection{Appendix} \label{app: Appendix Section}
Appendix Section \dots
\clearpage
\appendixsubsection{Sub-Appendix} \label{app: Appendix Subsection}
Sub-appendix \dots
\clearpage
\appendixsubsubsection{Subsub-Appendix} \label{app: Appendix Subsubsection}
Subsub-appendix \dots

\end{document}
```

Comment: you should increase the counters with `\refstepcounter` not \stepcounter. And don't ask two questions in one.

Comment: Thanks, that was easier than expected.